# Taking values from two tables

Tags: mysql

There are two tables: `pg_vendor_signup` and `pg_vendor_friends`:

```
pg_vendor_signup:
id vendor_id  name country_id
 1         3  ramu        381
 2         4   raj        381
 2         4  usha        381
 3         4 krian        381
 4         4  manu        381
 4         9 aswin        381

pg_vendor_friends:
vid fid status
1     9      4    
1     9      3
```

I want to get all names where `country_id` = 381 and get `status` field from `pg_vendor_friends`.

Comment: Format your table..its very hard to read your current format.

Answer (score 0):

Its not very clear what you want.

In case you want the `name` and `status` of all with `country_id` = `381` you can do:

```
select name,status 
from pg_vendor_signup,pg_vendor_friends
where id = vid and country_id = 381;
```

Comment: I wonder... should that be vendor_id=vid? Although I'd agree the OP is unclear.